# Direct2D – Drawing rectangeles and circles to large images and saving to disk

Tags: image-processing, graphics, direct2d, saving-data

My task is to draw a lot of simple geometric figures like rectangles and circles to large black-and-white images (about 4000x6000 pixels in size) and save the result to both, bitmap-files and a binary array representing each pixel as 1 if drawn or 0 otherwise. I was using GDI+ (=System.Drawing). Since this, however, took too long, I started having a look at Direct2D. I quickly learned how to draw to a Win32-window and thought I could use this to draw to a bitmap instead.

I learned how to load an image and display it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ee719658(v=vs.85).aspx
But I could not find information on how to create a large ID2D1Bitmap and render to it.

How can I create a render target (must that be a ID2D1HwndRenderTarget?) associated with such a newly created (how?) big bitmap and draw rectangles and circles to it and save it to file, afterwards?

Thank You very much for showing me the right direction,
Jürgen

Answer (score 0):

If I was to do it, I would roll my own code instead of using GDI or DirectX calls. The structure of a binary bitmap is very simple (packed array of bits), and once you have implemented a function to set a single pixel and one to draw a single run (horizontal line segment), drawing rectangles and circles comes easily.

If you don't feel comfortable with bit packing, you can work with a byte array instead (one pixel per byte), and convert the whole image in the end.

Writing the bitmap to a file is also not a big deal once you know about the binary file I/O operations (and you will find many ready-made functions on the Web).

---

Actually, when you know the specs of the layout of the bitmap file data, you don't need Windows at all.